# PIP install rasa-x takes forever

Tags: python, pip, miniconda, rasa, rasa-x

I am intalling Rasa X in a Python 3.7 conda environment on Windows 10. `pip` version is 20.3.3.

`pip3 install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`

It have been going on for 5-6 hours and seems to be confused:
[image]

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Try pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is caused by the dependency resolution backtracking logic introduced in pip v20.3.
([docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#dependency-resolution-backtracking))

A fix for now is to downgrade pip to v20.2, with:

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip==20.2
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of downgrading pip you can also use the old dependency resolver until pip 21.0 ships (that's when they strip the old resolver from the code base), like so:

```sh
pip3 install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

Answer (score 1):

After facing this issue for quite a while, I finally got if **fixed** after enquiring at rasa forum.

With `rasa==2.7.0` and `pip==20.2`, I ran the command `pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple` which was quick. It installed `rasa-x==0.40.1` for me.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of pip 21.3. also solves the problem. Just try and upgrade pip by using

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I downgraded pip to v 20.2. Then I had to download Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 and the issue is resolved.