# PIP install rasa-x is not working and pip downgrade too

Tags: python, pip, rasa, rasa-x

I have exactly the same problem as mentioned in [PIP install rasa-x takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806524/pip-install-rasa-x-takes-forever). In the Rasa installation guide they say, you have to create an environment first. Everytime I do: `conda create --name rasa python==3.7.6` it automatically downloads pip-20.3.3. If I now try the `pip install --upgrade pip==20.2` command it shows the following error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCoXf.png). What did I do wrong? Thanks for the help!

**Update: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip==20.2` worked, but now there is another problem when trying to install Rasa-X:[Rasa-X installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PBSE.png)

here is the code

```
(rasa) C:\Users\paul\Rasa Projekte\Bachelorbot>python -m pip install --upgrade pip==20.2
Collecting pip==20.2
  Using cached pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.3
Successfully installed pip-20.2

(rasa) C:\Users\paul\Rasa Projekte\Bachelorbot>pip3 install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
Collecting rasa-x
  Downloading https://pypi.rasa.com/api/package/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.35.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0 MB 2.2 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary<3.0.0,>=2.8.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (2.8.6)
Collecting attrs<20.0,>=19.3
  Using cached attrs-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pika<2.0.0,>=1.1.0
  Using cached pika-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (2.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: apscheduler<4.0,>=3.6 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (3.6.3)
Collecting GitPython<4.0.0,>=3.1.3
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.12-py3-none-any.whl (159 kB)
Processing c:\users\lord vader\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\35\61\a3\6d4ccd89ddf8fc937d8d1237fb857bc8f0d3d74e16bdc0bd03\sanic_jwt-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ruamel.yaml<0.17,>=0.16
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.16.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy<2.0.0,>=1.3.19 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (1.3.22)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (51.3.3.post20210118)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema<4.0,>=3.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (20.9.0)
Collecting kafka-python<2.0,>=1.4
  Using cached kafka_python-1.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (266 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.23 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: questionary<1.6.0,>=1.5.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.9,>=2.8 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (2.8.1)
Collecting alembic<2.0.0,>=1.0.10
  Using cached alembic-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting isodate<0.7,>=0.6
  Using cached isodate-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: sanic-cors<0.11.0,>=0.10.0b1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (0.10.0.post3)
Collecting ujson<2.0,>=1.35
  Using cached ujson-1.35.tar.gz (192 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa-x) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->rasa-x) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->rasa-x) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<0.5.0,>=0.4.4; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: coloredlogs<15,>=10 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn-crfsuite<0.4,>=0.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn<0.24,>=0.22 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib<0.16.0,>=0.15.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-probability<0.12,>=0.11 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex<2020.10,>=2020.6 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2020.9.27)
Requirement already satisfied: rasa-sdk<3.0.0,>=2.2.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle<1.5,>=1.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: twilio<6.46,>=6.26 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (6.45.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<21.0,>=20.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (20.8)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow_hub<0.10,>=0.9 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<3.4,>=3.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3<2.0,>=1.12 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.16.59)
Requirement already satisfied: webexteamssdk<1.7.0,>=1.1.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: terminaltables<3.2.0,>=3.1.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pykwalify<1.8.0,>=1.7.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyTelegramBotAPI<4.0.0,>=3.7.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo[srv,tls]<3.11,>=3.8 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: slackclient<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpickle<1.5,>=1.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sentry-sdk<0.20.0,>=0.17.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT[crypto]<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<4.51,>=4.31 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client==4.1.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.0,>=2.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pydot<1.5,>=1.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rocketchat_API<1.10.0,>=0.6.31 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.4,>=2.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorhash<1.1.0,>=1.0.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: colorclass<2.3,>=2.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fbmessenger<6.1.0,>=6.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (6.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-addons<=0.12,>=0.10 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aio-pika<7.0.0,>=6.7.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (6.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy<2.0.0,>=1.4.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-engineio<3.14,>=3.11 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py<0.11,>=0.9 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-socketio<4.7,>=4.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.6 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx<2.6,>=2.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz<2021.0,>=2019.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: async_generator<1.11,>=1.10 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: redis<4.0,>=3.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mattermostwrapper<2.3,>=2.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal>=1.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from apscheduler<4.0,>=3.6->rasa-x) (2.1)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.1.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version < "3.9"
  Using cached ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (118 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0,>=3.2->rasa-x) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0,>=3.2->rasa-x) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiofiles>=0.3.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets<9.0,>=8.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: httpx==0.15.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: httptools>=0.0.10 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.23->rasa-x) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.23->rasa-x) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.23->rasa-x) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.23->rasa-x) (2020.12.5)
Collecting python-editor>=0.3
  Using cached python_editor-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Processing c:\users\lord vader\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\2a\60\32\02a16820f96c067f6161ef35c21559f8db52c4158d6602b438\mako-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: sanic-plugins-framework>=0.9.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sanic-cors<0.11.0,>=0.10.0b1->rasa-x) (0.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->rasa-x) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->rasa-x) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<4.0.0,>=3.0.0->rasa-x) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=7.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from coloredlogs<15,>=10->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite<0.4,>=0.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.8.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-crfsuite>=0.8.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite<0.4,>=0.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn<0.24,>=0.22->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-probability<0.12,>=0.11->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.3.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-probability<0.12,>=0.11->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dm-tree in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-probability<0.12,>=0.11->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from packaging<21.0,>=20.0->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.8.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow_hub<0.10,>=0.9->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<3.4,>=3.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<3.4,>=3.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (8.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<3.4,>=3.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.59 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.12->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.19.59)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.12->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.12->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from webexteamssdk<1.7.0,>=1.1.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from webexteamssdk<1.7.0,>=1.1.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.11 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from pykwalify<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt>=0.6.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from pykwalify<1.8.0,>=1.7.0->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython<2.0.0,>=1.16.0; extra == "srv" in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from pymongo[srv,tls]<3.11,>=3.8->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==4.1.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==4.1.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==4.1.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2>=0.9.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client==4.1.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.0,>=2.0->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: typeguard>=2.7 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-addons<=0.12,>=0.10->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiormq<4,>=3.2.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from aio-pika<7.0.0,>=6.7.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.36.2)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.6.3)
Collecting smmap<4,>=3.0.1
  Using cached smmap-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->jsonschema<4.0,>=3.2->rasa-x) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.15.4->sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.15.4->sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: httpcore==0.11.* in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.15.4->sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (0.11.1)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.9.2
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4; python_version < "3.8" in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6->rasa-x) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from humanfriendly>=7.1->coloredlogs<15,>=10->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pamqp==2.3.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from aiormq<4,>=3.2.3->aio-pika<7.0.0,>=6.7.1->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.10,>=0.8 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from httpcore==0.11.*->httpx==0.15.4->sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2->rasa-x) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa<3.0.0,>=2.0.2->rasa-x) (3.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ujson
  Building wheel for ujson (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'E:\Temp\pip-wheel-fkr_1766'
       cwd: E:\Temp\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\ujson\
  Complete output (6 lines):
  Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
  Running setup.py clean for ujson
Failed to build ujson
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for ujson which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: attrs, pika, smmap, gitdb, GitPython, sanic-jwt, ruamel.yaml.clib, ruamel.yaml, kafka-python, python-editor, MarkupSafe, Mako, alembic, isodate, ujson, rasa-x
  Attempting uninstall: attrs
    Found existing installation: attrs 20.2.0
    Uninstalling attrs-20.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled attrs-20.2.0
  Attempting uninstall: sanic-jwt
    Found existing installation: sanic-jwt 1.5.0
    Uninstalling sanic-jwt-1.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled sanic-jwt-1.5.0
  Attempting uninstall: kafka-python
    Found existing installation: kafka-python 2.0.2
    Uninstalling kafka-python-2.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled kafka-python-2.0.2
  Attempting uninstall: ujson
    Found existing installation: ujson 3.2.0
    Uninstalling ujson-3.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled ujson-3.2.0
    Running setup.py install for ujson ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'E:\Temp\pip-record-_irr3a8y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\Include\ujson'
         cwd: E:\Temp\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\ujson\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ujson' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of ujson
  Moving to c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages\ujson-3.2.0.dist-info\
   from c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages\~json-3.2.0.dist-info
  Moving to c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages\ujson.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
   from E:\Temp\pip-uninstall-5a9ig65y\ujson.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\Temp\\pip-install-z3fmn3bn\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'E:\Temp\pip-record-_irr3a8y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\Include\ujson' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\anaconda\envs\rasa\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(rasa) C:\Users\paul\Rasa Projekte\Bachelorbot>
```

Comment: If you have issues with installing and configuring VC Build Tools, you can also download `ujson==1.35` wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ujson) and install it separately via `pip install path\to\ujson-...whl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue as well and for me installing pip packages with `python -m pip install <package>` worked. So `python -m pip install --upgrade pip==20.2` should work for you.

See here:

```
(rasa) C:\Users\<user>>pip install --upgrade pip==20.2
Collecting pip==20.2
  Downloading pip-20.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.8 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-qmjwuv0x\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


(rasa) C:\Users\<user>>python -m pip install --upgrade pip==20.2
Requirement already up-to-date: pip==20.2 in c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (20.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(rasa) C:\Users\<user>>pip --version
pip 20.2 from c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Edit: Answer for the update:
Hey it seems that you do not have Visual C++ Build tools installed.
Here is a guide on how to [install C++ Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools) on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! @cellularegg It worked, but now my Rasa-X installation is failing... I can't append screenshots, so I do it in the initial question on top below

Comment: Hey I Updated the answer. Basically you need to install C++ Build Tools see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools).

Comment: Thanks dude!! It worked. Thanks alot!

Comment: Hey I am glad that I could help. If possible, could you [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: Of course! Done