# Rasa installation issue using pip/pip3

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-core

I have created a new conda environment with python 3.8 -

```
conda create --name rasa_env
```

Then I am trying to install rasa using the command -

```
pip3 install rasa==2.8.18
```

as i want that version particularly.

However, it is throwing multiple dependency errors even in the new empty virtual environment such as -

> INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
> INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
> Downloading ruamel.yaml-0.16.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
> |████████████████████████████████| 111 kB 9.3 MB/s

Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output does not show any actual errors, so assuming the issue is a time-out during installation or it takes unusually long to install a package, this would be caused by the newly introduced pip dependency resolver. This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806524/pip-install-rasa-x-takes-forever). Try to upgrade pip to the newest version, where this issue is [reported to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70721262/17496163), via

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```